# Control number of target parquet files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have ~250 folders. Each folders in a day.
Each folder contains 24 parquet files.
I need to read them all, run on them a function, and write them after the change of the function.

When writing, I am doing this:

```
df
  .repartition('date)
  .write
  .partitionBy("date")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .parquet(outputPath)
```

But this "loses" the original split to 24 parts each date, and writes one file per date. Is there any option to split each day to n parts?

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the number of target partitions when doing a `repartition` - [scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@repartition(numPartitions:Int,partitionExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T])

```
df
  .repartition(numPartitions = 24, 'date)
  .write
  .partitionBy("date")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .parquet(outputPath)
```

## Edit

I just realized `numPartitions` is the number of resulting partitions in total. Thus you may try passing it the number of days times the number of splits you want per file, *e.g.* `numPartitions = 24 * 250` - however, there is no guarantee that all days will have exactly 24 splits, especially if the amount of data for each day is drastically different.